# onClick event for container having duplicate IDs

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know Its weird, but the existing code I'm working have Duplicate ID's instead of class.

```
<div class="67275686" id="sy_brn"><b>Some Text Goes Here 1</b></div>
<div class="1227552" id="sy_brn"><b>Some Text Goes Here 2</b></div>
<div class="4527552" id="sy_brn"><b>Some Text Goes Here 3</b></div>
```

i'm tying to get value of class using `sy_brn` ID.

expecting to get value like-

```
$('#sy_brn').click(function() { 
var value = $(this).attr('class');
});
```

its not working as multiple ID on same page not works.
I don't have the flexibility to convert all <div IDs to class.

Is there any way I can trigger click for sy_brn ID & get value of class?

Comment: try `$('[id="sy_brn"]').click(`

Comment: It's not only weird, it's invalid to have multiple elements with the same `id`. I'd correct that, but if that's not possible, I'd query for all the elements based on some other aspect that they have in common, like their position in the DOM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)

```js
const els = document.querySelectorAll("#sy_brn");
els.forEach(el => el.addEventListener("click", ev => alert(ev.currentTarget.classList)));
```

```html
<div class="67275686" id="sy_brn"><b>Some Text Goes Here 1</b></div>
<div class="1227552" id="sy_brn"><b>Some Text Goes Here 2</b></div>
<div class="4527552" id="sy_brn"><b>Some Text Goes Here 3</b></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the below snippet. I think it will work.

```
$('div[id="sy_brn"]').click(function() { 
  var value = $(this).attr('class');
  console.log(value)
});
```